# oracle delete data from remote SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, oracle, transfer

Using the procedure below, we are trying to transfer data from SQL Server to oracle, but we get the error :

> Tarih : 20/01/2011, Hata yeri :
>   pr_get_customer, Hata Açıklaması:
>   -28500 => v_trace : 2,v_transfer_id :1ORA-28500: ORACLE sisteminden Oracle
>   olmayan sisteme bağlantı şu mesajı
>   verdi: [Oracle][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][SQL Server]The multi-part
>   identifier
>   "PUBLIC.TMP_CUSTOMER.TRANSFER_ID"
>   could not be bound. {42000,NativeErr =
>   4104} ORA-02063: önceki 2 lines,
>   kaynağı DBLINK_NAV2

v trace is our variable to locate the region of the error, and transfer_id gets value .

The procedure is listed here :

```
PROCEDURE pr_get_customer
   IS
      CURSOR cur_tmp_customer
      IS
         SELECT "TRANSFER_ID" AS transfer_id, "INSERT_DATE" AS insert_date,
                "OP_TYPE" AS op_type, "STATUS" AS status, "No_" AS NO,
                "Name" AS NAME, "Name 2" AS name_2, "Address" AS address,
                "Address 2" AS address_2, "City" AS city,
                "Phone No_" AS phone_no, "Chain Name" AS chain_name,
                "Customer Price Group" AS customer_price_group,
                "Blocked" AS blocked,
                "Bill-to Customer No_" AS bill_to_customer_no,
                "Fax No_" AS fax_no, "SUBE" AS sube, "Alt Grup" AS alt_grup,
                "Location Code" AS location_code
           FROM nav_tmp_customer
          WHERE "STATUS" = 0
            AND ("TRANSFER_ID" > (SELECT NVL (MAX (transfer_id), 0)
                                    FROM t_tmp_customer));

      r_tmp_customer     cur_tmp_customer%ROWTYPE;

      TYPE tmp_customer_tbl_typ IS TABLE OF cur_tmp_customer%ROWTYPE;

      tmp_customer_tbl   tmp_customer_tbl_typ       := tmp_customer_tbl_typ
                                                                           ();
      v_trace            INTEGER                    := 0;
      v_transfer_id      NUMBER (28, 0)             := 0;
   BEGIN
      OPEN cur_tmp_customer;

      FETCH cur_tmp_customer
      BULK COLLECT INTO tmp_customer_tbl;

      CLOSE cur_tmp_customer;

      FOR x IN 1 .. tmp_customer_tbl.COUNT ()
      LOOP
         BEGIN
            v_trace := 1;

            INSERT INTO esiparis.t_tmp_customer
                        (transfer_id,
                         insert_date,
                         op_type,
                         status,
                         NO, NAME,
                         name2,
                         address,
                         address2,
                         city,
                         phone_no,
                         chain_name,
                         customer_price_group,
                         blocked,
                         bill_to_customer_no,
                         location_code,
                         fax_no,
                         sube,
                         alt_grup
                        )
                 VALUES (tmp_customer_tbl (x).transfer_id,
                         tmp_customer_tbl (x).insert_date,
                         tmp_customer_tbl (x).op_type,
                         tmp_customer_tbl (x).status,
                         tmp_customer_tbl (x).NO, tmp_customer_tbl (x).NAME,
                         tmp_customer_tbl (x).name_2,
                         tmp_customer_tbl (x).address,
                         tmp_customer_tbl (x).address_2,
                         tmp_customer_tbl (x).city,
                         tmp_customer_tbl (x).phone_no,
                         tmp_customer_tbl (x).chain_name,
                         tmp_customer_tbl (x).customer_price_group,
                         tmp_customer_tbl (x).blocked,
                         tmp_customer_tbl (x).bill_to_customer_no,
                         tmp_customer_tbl (x).location_code,
                         tmp_customer_tbl (x).fax_no,
                         tmp_customer_tbl (x).sube,
                         tmp_customer_tbl (x).alt_grup
                        );

            COMMIT;
            v_trace := 2;
            v_transfer_id := tmp_customer_tbl (x).transfer_id;

            DELETE FROM nav_tmp_customer
                  WHERE "TRANSFER_ID" = v_transfer_id;

            COMMIT;
            v_trace := 3;
         EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS
            THEN
               ROLLBACK;
               pck_helper.pr_log_error (SQLCODE,
                                           'v_trace : '
                                        || v_trace
                                        || ',v_transfer_id :'
                                        || v_transfer_id
                                        || SQLERRM,
                                        'pr_get_customer'
                                       );
         END;
      END LOOP;
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
         ROLLBACK;
         pck_helper.pr_log_error (SQLCODE,
                                  'v_trace : ' || v_trace || ',' || SQLERRM,
                                  'pr_get_customer'
                                 );
   END pr_**strong text****strong text****strong text**get_customer;
```

Any ideas are appreciated,

---

UPDATE :
Working procedure is as below

```
PROCEDURE pr_get_item
IS
  CURSOR cur_tmp_item
  IS
     SELECT "TRANSFER_ID" AS transfer_id, "INSERT_DATE" AS insert_date,
            "OP_TYPE" AS op_type, "STATUS" AS status, "No_" AS NO,
            "Description" AS description,
            "Base Unit of Measure" AS base_unit_of_measure,
            "Inventory Posting Group" AS inventory_posting_group,
            "Net Weight" AS net_weight,
            "Genel Ürün Sahibi" AS genel_urun_sahibi,
            "Tab Code" AS tab_code,
            "Tab Unit of Measure" AS tab_unit_of_measure,
            "TAB Qty_ per Unit of Measure"
                                          AS tab_qty_per_unit_of_measure,
            "Blocked 2" AS blocked_2
       FROM nav_tmp_item
      WHERE "STATUS" = 0
        AND ("TRANSFER_ID" > (SELECT NVL (MAX (transfer_id), 0)
                                FROM t_tmp_item));

  r_tmp_item     cur_tmp_item%ROWTYPE;

  TYPE tmp_item_tbl_typ IS TABLE OF cur_tmp_item%ROWTYPE;

  tmp_item_tbl   tmp_item_tbl_typ       := tmp_item_tbl_typ ();
  v_trace        INTEGER                := 0;
  v_count        NUMBER (28, 0)         := 1;
BEGIN
  OPEN cur_tmp_item;

  FETCH cur_tmp_item
  BULK COLLECT INTO tmp_item_tbl;

  CLOSE cur_tmp_item;

  FOR x IN 1 .. tmp_item_tbl.COUNT ()
  LOOP
     BEGIN
        v_trace := 1;

        INSERT INTO esiparis.t_tmp_item
                    (transfer_id,
                     insert_date,
                     op_type, status,
                     NO, description,
                     base_unit_of_measure,
                     inventory_posting_group,
                     net_weight,
                     genel_urun_sahibi,
                     tab_code,
                     tab_unit_of_measure,
                     tab_qty_per_unit_of_measure,
                     blocked_2
                    )
             VALUES (tmp_item_tbl (x).transfer_id,
                     tmp_item_tbl (x).insert_date,
                     tmp_item_tbl (x).op_type, tmp_item_tbl (x).status,
                     tmp_item_tbl (x).NO, tmp_item_tbl (x).description,
                     tmp_item_tbl (x).base_unit_of_measure,
                     tmp_item_tbl (x).inventory_posting_group,
                     tmp_item_tbl (x).net_weight,
                     tmp_item_tbl (x).genel_urun_sahibi,
                     tmp_item_tbl (x).tab_code,
                     tmp_item_tbl (x).tab_unit_of_measure,
                     tmp_item_tbl (x).tab_qty_per_unit_of_measure,
                     tmp_item_tbl (x).blocked_2
                    );

        COMMIT;
        v_trace := 2;

        DELETE FROM nav_tmp_item
              WHERE "TRANSFER_ID" = tmp_item_tbl (x).transfer_id;

        COMMIT;
        v_trace := 3;
     EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS
        THEN
           ROLLBACK;
           pck_helper.pr_log_error (SQLCODE,
                                    'v_trace : ' || v_trace || ','
                                    || SQLERRM,
                                    'pr_get_item'
                                   );
     END;
  END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS
  THEN
     ROLLBACK;
     pck_helper.pr_log_error (SQLCODE,
                              'v_trace : ' || v_trace || ',' || SQLERRM,
                              'pr_get_item'
                             );
END pr_get_item;
```

Comment: What's the point of a Rollback in the error handler when you're commiting TWICE in the loop?

Comment: Stephanie, logical point. We tried to add by iteration to the procedure. This procedure is derived from a procedure alike, and at that procedure - same bug remains - we tested to get data first and delete remote db later.

Comment: Another point is that it gave an error that I didn't take the exact note of it but we could recover that only by dropping table. If that was a production db, it would be unacceptible :( .. The error occured while tracing the code with debug at remote delete.

Comment: so this isn't the exact code, this has accommodations made for debugging. OK, So are you sure you have DELETE permissions on the SQL Server side?

Comment: yes, the only difference is the tables, nav_tmp_customer is symb. link to tmp_customer at sql server, nav_tmp_item is symb. link to tmp_item at sql server at the other proc. tmp customer had problem with name field so we had to re-create table by changing VARCHAR to NVARCHAR

Comment: I would like to share the other proc, maybe the whole package, there is something missing from the eye I guess. The other proc was developed and tested last night, and we produced this one using the first one.

Comment: marc_s , thank you for the formatting

Comment: got the same error when removed commit. If insert and delete is done in the same cursor loop this error occurs : <pre><code>ORA-01591: kilit belirsiz dağıtılmış 3.10.5910 işlemi tarafından tutuluyor
</code>

Comment: couldn't resolve ora-01591 even though tried docs at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752984/ora-01591-oracle-delete-data-from-remote-sql-server-table

Comment: TRUNCATE TABLE T_TMP_CUSTOMER as a low level resolution. Shows that I need to read,read and read distr. transactions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the better question is: What's the best way to move data from SQL Server to Oracle which deletes from MSSS every successfully delivered row?

You do these in a loop to makes sure that when you add to one, you delete from the other.

If some unknown random thing happens to error on the insert, you'll avoid removing the source record.

That's the gist, right?

There are much better ways to handle this kind of data movement then committing after each insert/delete distributed transaction loop.

First off a commit in the middle of a loop is just bad. In Oracle it's a good way to cause other sessions to get ORA-01555 errors. So I would avoid that if possible.

Second you should absolutely know what are the possible causes for reasonable errors on insert. You violate a column length, a FK, a UK... there's a finite list of what could break on insert. Big hairy bad breaks like Unable to extend tablespace SHOULD cause the system to grind to a halt. No need to trap for that. But application issues like I mentioned are easy to manage for.

If I were writing this, I would bulk insert all of the rows using Oracle's [LOG ERRORS INTO](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/DmlErrorLogging_10gR2.php) to avoid a full ROLLBACK when only one/few row(s) fail.

Now you have a table which contains every failed row and the reason it failed. Now you can on the SQL Server side, delete all the rows NOT IN the list of failed ID's.

You've accomplished the same thing but with Set based operations instead of SLOW-BY-SLOW, ooops, I mean row by row.

Comment: Hmm, good points. Thank you very much for the LOG_ERRORS_INTO tip. ORA-28534: Heterogeneous Services preprocessing error is part of this story now, because of the date-time Field. This time we are trying to send the orders from Oracle to Sql-Server. Wonder if I will live enough to see ORA-001 NO ERRORS LIFE IS GOOD

Comment: One point of doing in the loop was, to avoid deleting source records that are just inserted during my process. I have to keep the numbers in VARRAY or something, then I have to MINUS with the LOG ERRORS INTO to get the id number of the source records to be deleted.

Comment: I don't understand the last comment. You have a fistful of rows to move. Are you saying that the definition of that fistful isn't simple. I would have guessed that it was all the row with a timestamp > than the last time I moved them and <= the start time of my current operation. If it's just a range like that, then all you need to know is the failures, successes are everything else _in that time range_. Are you saying it's not the case that the range is defined so easily.