# ORA-01591 - oracle delete data from remote sql server table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Using a heterogenous connection from Oracle 11gr2 to Sql Server 2005, we are trying to fetch data. While fetching in a loop, if we don't commit after inserting the data to Oracle, and try to delete the data at Sql Server this error occurs  :

```
ORA-01591: kilit belirsiz dağıtılmış 3.10.5910 işlemi tarafından tutuluyor
```

This problem keeps on going until re-creating the table. We would be very happy to hear if any logical, humanistic approach exists?

Comment: So this is using Oracle's Database Link to connect to SQL Server, or SQL Server's Linked Servers to connect to the Oracle instance?  It might help to see the code, even if somewhat abstracted.

Comment: oracle to sql server..  I have found some ora doc about it but it didn't work though I tried to force commit etc. link is <link>http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10739/ds_txnman.htm</link>

Comment: OMG Ponies , the code is at my other question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751816/oracle-delete-data-from-remote-sql-server-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the real answer is at http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10739/ds_txnman.htm, connecting as sys , doing FORCE COMMIT 'tranid' etc. is explained there. But in my case, it didn't work. As a dirty resolution I truncated the table , if there was no data waiting to be commited and that locks the delete operation, there wouldn't be any - temporarly- problem , I thought. 
TRUNCATE TMP_CUSTOMER is my - dirty - solution to this.
Please do not hesitate to answer because it is a temp solution, also some good advice on distr. transactions would be good too.